# simple rsync in crontab without password

Tags: rsync

I would like to run the following: (Centos 5.4)

`rsync -avz /source_folder  192.168.1.1:/destination_folder`

right now I'm running it from CLI but eventually I would like to run it from crontab (user:root).

when I run it, it always asks me to enter root password.
I want to skip the password. I've seen a few of the answers regarding this but it either doesn't work or I'm not sure I understand completely how to do it.
can someone assist?

Answer (score 14):

As others have said you can do this with passphrase-less ssh keys. This is inherently insecure and you need to take additional steps to add some security back into the process. What I do is restrict the key's use to [a host and a command](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch08_02.htm). I've written this up from my notes, I don't think I've missed any steps out.

The first thing to do is to generate a public key pair that will be used solely for this backup process. When prompted for a pass phrase just press enter twice.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "For Backup use only"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/root/.ssh/id_rsa): /root/.ssh/backup.id_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/backup.id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/backup.id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:65:c0:cb:2b:9e:18:ff:b2:59:d4:b5:e8:ae:84:32:2b
```

Transfer the public key `/root/.ssh/backup.id_rsa.pub` to the remote host and add it to the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

On the remote host restrict the use of the public key by adding `from=` and `command=` restrictions. Edit the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, locate the backup key and add the address/name of the host that will be running the cron job as well as a command to run. This command will be run when something logs in with this key e.g.

```
from="192.168.254.207",command="/root/checkrsync",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...
```

You can only use this key from 192.168.254.207 and you can only run the command /root/checkrsync and other functionality has been removed too.

Edit the file /root/checkrsync like this

`echo $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND >/tmp/rsync.cmd`

save it and make it executable

`chmod 700 /root/checkrsync`

We'll change `/root/checkrsync` later once we know what $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND is.

On the host where we'll be running the cron job run the rsync command interactively

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e "/usr/bin/ssh -i /root/.ssh/backup.id_rsa" /source_folder root@remote.host:/destination_folder
```

Don't worry about any error messages we only want to generate the /tmp/rsync.cmd file on the remote host

On the remote host make an exact note of the contents of the /tmp/rsync.cmd file (it will be something like `rsync --server -vlogDtprze.iLs . /destination_folder`).

On the remote host edit `/root/checkrsync` and change it to

```
if [[ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" == "rsync --server -vlogDtprze.iLs . /destination_folder" ]]
then
     $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
fi
```

where the right hand side of the if statement is what was in /tmp/rsync.cmd.

Test the setup. On the host where we'll be running the cron job run the rsync command interactively again

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e "/usr/bin/ssh -i /root/.ssh/backup.id_rsa" /source_folder root@remote.host:/destination_folder
```

Now it should run correctly if it does then install it into your crontab.

```
crontab -e 

* 1 * * *  /usr/bin/rsync -avz -e "/usr/bin/ssh -i /root/.ssh/backup.id_rsa" /source_folder root@remote.host:/destination_folder
```

Comment: With the "from=" restriction, is there an ability to restrict to any ip in a particular range? i.e. 196.168.1.1 - 196.168.1.255

Comment: @thames: What you can do is detailed in the man pages http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys not it also refers to the PATTERNS section of http://man.he.net/man5/ssh_config

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up passphrase-less [ssh key authentication](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/532.cfm).

Bear in mind security concerns when setting this up. I recommend using a [host access list](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/jpmg/ssh/authorized_keys_howto.html) to restrict the source IP using the key.

Answer (score 2):

Check following link for seting up SSH keys. SSh keys will help you to setup password less ssh login.

http://techtrunch.com/linux/ssh-keys

Setting up CRON:

1. Login as root
2. Open a terminal and type `crontab -e`, then enter following

   1 * * * * rsync -avz /source_folder 192.168.1.1:/destination_folder

Note

This will run on every hour.

Answer (score 0):

For ssh without password (or rsync over ssh), you'll need a **key pair** without a passphrase.

You can generate your the pair (private & public key) on your **source** machine by `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`), then add your public key (contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the **destination** machine to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Read the whole article on cron rsync backups:
https://medium.com/@deltazero/linux-remote-backup-rsync-chroot-d797ba6babe5