# Trying to setup chroot'd rsync

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync, sftp, chroot

I'm trying to set up a backup server.
I want to **chroot** each user (client) to its home directory, and only allow it to use **sftp** and **rsync**.

I quickly discovered that I was not the only one trying to do something like this, and I found [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP-chroot) and followed it. So now I've got chroot'd users with sftp only.

Then I found out that rsync needs ssh to spawn itself on the other machine, and that sftp is not enough. Giving each user an ssh login is something that I wanted to avoid in the first place.

Can anyone think of some possible solutions?

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: Have a look at this answer I wrote some time go http://serverfault.com/questions/255084/simple-rsync-in-crontab-without-password/255132#255132

Answer (score 13):

An sftp solution would *also* require an ssh login for everyone, so you haven't really lost anything here.  Granting ssh access does not necessarily imply full shell access, for example, [this](http://ramblings.narrabilis.com/using-rsync-with-ssh) shows how to use the ssh `authorized_keys` file to allow backup via rsync while limiting available commands to *just* the rsync receiver.

In fact, if you opt for key based authentication, rather than password authentication (which you should), you could then run everything under one user account instead of requiring multiple accounts.  You would use keys to identify remote users, and direct the rsync receiver at a particular directory.

Something like this, in your `authorized_keys` file:

```
command="/usr/bin/rsync --server -a . /tmp/user1" ssh-rsa ... user1
command="/usr/bin/rsync --server -a . /tmp/user2" ssh-rsa ... user2
```

Someone using the `user1` private key will backup into `/tmp/user1`, and someone using the `user2` private key will backup into `/tmp/user2`.  And so forth...

Comment: Link is gone 404.

Comment: I've updated the link.

Answer (score 7):

Execute usual `rsync` from client to remote server, but add additional verbose switch: `SSH -v`, then grep for `Sending command`. 
You will see exact command client is sending to remote server:

```
rsync -avz -e'ssh -v -i /ssh-keys/clientprivate.key' --bwlimit=8000 --delete root@server:/path/ /backup/myserver/ 2>&1 | grep "Sending command"
```

In my case, it was

```
rsync --server -vvlogDtprze.iLsf --bwlimit=8000 --delete . /path
```

Add this as `command="..."` to remote server `/home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys` file as @larsks mentioned.
Add aditional security settings, if necessary:

`no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2..CPhIJ+LVULWz arnis@server`

All together:

```
command="rsync --server -vvlogDtprze.iLsf --bwlimit=8000 --delete . /backup/path",no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding,no-pty,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2..CPhIJ+LVULWz arnis@server
```

(Taken from very good tutorial http://en.positon.org/post/Rsync-command-restriction-over-SSH)

Comment: Good 1st answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to provide some form of shell access to be able to use rsync unless you are connecting directly to the rsync server - default port is 873 (TCP).

From the [rysnc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> **There are two different ways for rsync to contact a remote system:
>   using a remote-shell program as the
>   transport (such as ssh or rsh) or
>   contacting an rsync daemon directly
>   via TCP.** The remote-shell transport
>   is used whenever the source or
>   destination path contains a single
>   colon (:) separator after a host
>   specification. Contacting an rsync
>   daemon directly happens when the
>   source or destination path contains a
>   double colon (::) separator after a
>   host specification, OR when an
>   rsync:// URL is specified (see also
>   the lqUSING RSYNC-DAEMON FEATURES VIA
>   A REMOTE-SHELL CONNECTIONrq section
>   for an exception to this latter rule).

To provide limited shell access, consider the following [guide](http://www.drdobbs.com/implementing-rsync-only-access-over-chro/199102089). (Note: the original link is dead)  Summary:

> This setup combines the best features
>   from rsync, SSH, and chroot. Rsync
>   provides the flexibility and
>   efficiency in files transfer, SSH
>   protects the data being transferred,
>   and chroot protects data on the server
>   from unauthorized access. The dummysh
>   limits the access to rsync only.
>
> While rsync server implements chroot,
>   it lacks the SSH protection that is
>   often required. Besides, opening an
>   additional rsync server port presents
>   a security risk and sometimes is not
>   possible either technically or
>   politically. Sftp and scp lack the
>   flexibility and efficiency provided by
>   rsync, especially when a directory
>   tree is involved, such as a Web site.

Or take a look at using [rssh](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rssh.conf) (there is a guide to setting up rssh [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/rhel-centos-linux-install-configure-rssh-shell.html)):

> rssh is a restricted shell for use
>   with OpenSSH, allowing only scp and/or
>   sftp. It now also includes support for
>   rdist, rsync, and cvs. For example, if
>   you have a server which you only want
>   to allow users to copy files off of
>   via scp, without providing shell
>   access, you can use rssh to do that.

Comment: [Current news](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=87k40lckrn.fsf%40windlord.stanford.edu&forum_name=rssh-discuss) is that rssh is not being maintained and has some odd security hole. Check back the current state before investing in it.

Comment: You can use the perl script `rrsync` instead of rssh, included in the official rsync package. See http://derek.simkowiak.net/backing-up-multiple-servers-with-rsnapshot/

Answer (score 1):

**Rsync into chroot is tricky** :) You'll need to setup minimal environment for /bin/sh and /usr/bin/rsync within the chrooted directory (destination-side) in order for it to work.

See the whole article here, the rsync-environment setup is by the end
https://medium.com/@deltazero/linux-remote-backup-rsync-chroot-d797ba6babe5

Comment: Sadly this didn't help the rsync issue I was running into.
`rsync: [Receiver] change_dir#3 "..." failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(827) [Receiver=3.2.7]` When trying to rsync into chrootdirectory rbash user.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a shell that wraps rsync.

look at the general idea here: https://sixohthree.com/1458/locking-down-rsync-using-ssh

in your wrapping shell you can do what you want and maybe chroot the user.

In my case I needed to switch on virtual account using the same *nix user. I manage to do so using this kind of shell plus many lines in the authorized_keys file. I have not chrooted the user but I've added a user folder level in the rsync server command.

look at [process user differently using ssh key](https://serverfault.com/questions/825878/process-user-differently-using-ssh-key)

Answer (score 0):

**SFTP with Rsync capabilities, without a shell**

You can use [LFTP+SFTP in a chroot environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/836103/replace-scp-with-sftp/836136#836136) and achieve the same results as using rsync, without providing the user a shell or doing any heavy customizations in ssh with wrappers.

This is more secure and can be substantially faster.