# How to setup a public rsync and sftp server

Tags: ssh, rsync, sftp, chroot

I want to setup a public storage server which allows `sftp` and `rsync` (through ssh). I've got it working with a `chroot` jail and `rssh`. When the user connects to the server with `sftp` he can read all the files in the chroot jail (like /lib and /bin) in the `chroot`. Likewise with `rsync` (`rsync --list-only user@server:/`). I would like to have a setup where to user can only view and not leave his home directory.

An additional requirement is that the I don't want to setup a chroot environment for each user.

I already tried the chrootdirectory and forcecommand statements in `sshd_config` which works great for `sftp` but does not allow any `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

for the sftp part you might look at the directives [*Subsystem sftp internal-sftp*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/SFTP#Chrooted_SFTP-only_Accounts) together with ChrootDirectory in the sshd_config.

Comment: Already tried that good for sftp but not for rsync

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to setup commands on the accepted keys as proposed in [Trying to setup chroot'd rsync](https://serverfault.com/questions/287578/trying-to-setup-chrootd-rsync) ?

Excerpt:

> Granting ssh access does not necessarily imply full shell access, for example, this shows how to use the ssh authorized_keys file to allow backup via rsync while limiting available commands to just the rsync receiver.
>
> Something like this, in your authorized_keys file:
>
> ```
> command="/usr/bin/rsync --server -a . /tmp/user1" ssh-rsa ... user1
> command="/usr/bin/rsync --server -a . /tmp/user2" ssh-rsa ... user2
> ```

There's also pointers to two blog articles. The first explains how to restrict ssh to rsync:

- http://en.positon.org/post/Rsync-command-restriction-over-SSH

The second what you don't want, setting up a chroot environment.

- http://en.positon.org/post/SFTP-chroot-rsync

Personally I would go for the chroot and setting `$USER/{bin|lib}` as bind mounts. This way I would maintain a single chroot environment mounted on every user's chroot.

Comment: The bind mounts are a good idea but then the user will still be able to see them with rsync, right?

Comment: Can I combine command's in the authorized_keys file to include rsync and sftp?

Comment: re: bind mounts, they would be able to see bin and lib but that shouldn't be a problem, it's only binaries and libs.