# process user differently using ssh key

Tags: ssh, rsync, chroot

I wonder if it is possible to chroot/chdir/process the same unix user differently using the ssh key used in the ssh connexion...

The use case could be a rsync server using only one linux/local user for many virtual account.

It's somewhat how github/gitlab manages users.

EDIT: chrooting is not the main point. The point is to differentiate 'virtual' account using the same *nix user but with different SSH keys. Chrooting is a bonus.

PS: I've cooked a quick POC on a F25 server.

Comment: thank you for the -1 without even an explanation: coward or pretentious

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/287578/trying-to-setup-chrootd-rsync) - the first answer looks like it will help. (I didn't downvote btw)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate of THIS one. But I mislaid things when I spoke about chroot. I'll reformulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want different chroots, but the trick is usually to identify the users in authorized_keys. Take this example from Gitolite:

```
command="/usr/share/gitolite/gl-auth-command john",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA...
```

The `gl-auth-command` then knows who it is, even though everbody signs in with user `git`.

Comment: nice lead thx I'll come back in a while after testing

Comment: using `command="/path/to/rsync_wrapper john" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA...` was the good idea.
More on wrapping ssh commands: https://sixohthree.com/1458/locking-down-rsync-using-ssh

Comment: And you can optimize your key search  with https://blog.heckel.xyz/2015/05/04/openssh-authorizedkeyscommand-with-fingerprint/