# Replace scp with sftp

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp

We have a few synchronization scripts for a client sending files, using scp, to a remote server administered by one of their providers. Recently they closed it, and the new one they provided doesn't permit scp, only sftp (there is no way to get a shell on the remote server, so scp / rsync can't work).

Is there a somewhat simple way to replace scp in the scripts by sftp ? I guess the easiest I know of would be to use sshfs and use cp instead of scp, but that's very ugly.

Looks like sftp can be passed a file with commands in it using -b, but that means re-coding parts of the scripts. I was wondering if there were any way to use sftp as a drop in replacement to scp, or some other package that would provide a similar functionality ? (i.e sftp /source user@remote:/dest or something like that, it'd be perfect if I could just sed the scripts to replace only the command)

Thanks

Comment: PuTTY has a commandline utility `pscp` which is similar to OpenSSH `scp` but can manually specify scp or sftp protocol; I've only used this on Windows but [the FAQ says the Unix port includes it](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-unix)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Rsync over sftp or chroot sftp**

**Edit:** To be clear, the **[LFTP](https://lftp.yar.ru/features.html)** client supports numerous protocols, including FTP, HTTP, FISH, SFTP, HTTPS, FTPS and BitTorrent.  In this example, we are using **SFTP**.  The client name has caused some confuion from folks reading this post.

You can use `lftp` and it's mirror sub-system to replicate the behavior of rsync over SFTP.  This works in chroot environments as well.

```
lftp -u username, \
-e "set net:timeout 4;set net:max-retries 6;mirror -R --parallel=8 --no-perms --newer-than=now-2days --only-newer /source/ /source/;bye" sftp://hostname.domain
```

In this example, I left out the password, because we have an SSH key trust to the destination host.

**Note:** The `-R` does not mean recursive.  The `-R` flag means push to remote.

`--parallel=` is the number of threads to break the job up into.  This *can be* limited or impacted of course by MaxStartups in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and nofile pam limits and other limits on the target server.

`net:max-retries 6` I like to retry, just in case there was a network maintenance.

`net:timeout 4` give up, then retry after 4 seconds.

`--no-perms` if you don't wish to change perms on the remote end.

`--newer-than` is just an example of something to use as needed.

`--loop` can be used to repeat the sync until there are not changes detected.

`bye` we don't want to forget to log out instead of relying on idle timeout.

There are [many other options available](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lftp) in LFTP.

I have had great experiences with LFTP using it's mirror sub-system and SFTP.  It is substantially faster, as it can break jobs up into multiple streams.  It can even break up a single file into multiple streams.

A **major security advantage** of using LFTP is allowing file transfers in environments where you don't want the automation scripts to have access to a shell on the remote end.

I created a working demo that you are welcome to test with.  File retention is low, but you are welcome to use this to see how easy it is to automate pushing directories / files using **lftp** plus **sftp chroot**.  Simply install **lftp** and then create some temp dirs or files, then:

```
mkdir -p ~/sftp_test/`date '+%Y%m%d%H%M'`/{1,2,3}/{a,b,c}
lftp -u anon, -e "set net:timeout 4;set net:max-retries 4;mirror -R --parallel=4 --no-perms ~/sftp_test/ /private/;bye" sftp://ohftp.org
```

Comment: Well, that does seem to work very well. Thanks a lot for a very complete answer !

Comment: My pleasure.  I am glad that worked for you.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a batchfile aproximation:

```
sftp -b batchfile [user@]host
```

a batchfile includes a sequence of commands that must reproduce "scp" operation with equivalent ftp commands:

```
cd remote_dir
lcd local_dir
put file
```