# How to download images from one server to another

Tags: wget

I have a VPS running Centos.

I also have a site (say, example.com) hosted on separate, shared hosting. I would like to backup all images in the "images" folder, which consist of the following structure:

example.com/images/mammals

example.com/images/reptiles

example.com/images/birds

The files can be .JPG, .PNG and .GIF

How do I backup the entire folder from the shared hosting to my VPS?

Would I use wget? If yes, what would be the command(s)?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

Best way to synchronize remote folders is `rsync`. To have security use `rsync` over `ssh`.

So first make sure that you can use `ssh` and `rsync` on VPS server.

If you do not have `rsync`, then you can use `wget --mirror`. With `wget` you can filter which file pattern to download.

Comment: Thank you Mircea. Could you please kindly show the commands to use? I can definitely use rsync and ssh on the VPS. Thanks!

Comment: For a complete example of rsync over ssh, take a look on: http://serverfault.com/questions/255084/simple-rsync-in-crontab-without-password